# Oracle SQL script execution from command line

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have created the following file called tabledeletion.sql and it has the following code:

```
declare 
cnt_t int default null;
begin

select count(*) into cnt_t from user_tables where table_name = 'SPORT';

if cnt_t > 0 then
    execute immediate 'drop table SPORT cascade constraints';
    cnt_t := 0;
end if;

select count(*) into cnt_t from user_tables where table_name = 'VENUE';

if cnt_t > 0 then
    execute immediate 'drop table VENUE cascade constraints';
    cnt_t := 0;
end if;
```

I connect to my Oracle 10g and through the sql command prompt I give in the 
following command:

```
SQL> @tabledeletion
```

But nothing happens. Why is this happening? Thank you.

Nick

Comment: Append `end;` and `/` lines to your .sql-file

Comment: Thank you @EgorSkriptunoff. That worked. Please make your comment an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Egor Skriptunoff 's comment, i needed to add `end;` and `/` lines to my sql file.

Comment: Could you please share the complete resulting SQL file?